# Possible causes of "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid pc in LineNumberTable"

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

Today I started coding a project that uses sqlite and when I tried to test it I received the **java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid pc in LineNumberTable**. Hope you can help me with it, because I'm just lost. I'v searched about this error, and came across some weird solutions to some weird causes. As I understand, none of them was causing my problem.

I'm using "sqlitejdbc-v056" wich is inserted in my classpath.

**Edit:** My JDK version is 1.7.0_03-b05

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid pc in LineNumberTable in     class file Controllers/FuncionariosController
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Code giving the error:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    DatabaseController db=new DatabaseController();
    FuncionariosController f=new FuncionariosController(db);
        ...
     } 
}
```

Class FuncionarioController:

```
package Controllers;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Models.Funcionario;

public class FuncionariosController {
    private DatabaseController db;

    public FuncionariosController(DatabaseController db){
        this.db=db;
    }

    public void render(String cargo){
        ...
    }
    public List<Funcionario> selectAll(){
        ...
    }
    public Funcionario select(String login){
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Apparently, the problem is about the JDK version you're using to compile some classes. Please add the JDK version you're working with.

Comment: Try to use JDK 1.6 to compile your project.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall 1.7 or it's possible to have both? How do I specify which one to use in eclipse? Thnaks for helping, by the way :)

Comment: You can have both installed in your PC. There is [this manual](http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/itk168/Updating%20the%20default%20JDK%20in%20Eclipse.pdf) on how to change the JDK in Eclipse, while the tutorial is on Windows, you can use the same Eclipse steps in another platform like Linux.

Comment: Ok, I did it, and it compiles now. Does it mean I will have to use JDK1.6 for this project? Because I had to comment out a lot of code to make it run, like switch(string) and such.........

Comment: That I don't know :(. Maybe you should post another question about this problem so the community can help you with that specific new problem.

Comment: We are having this problem too, in Eclipse, with JDK 1.7.  This has been working, although we had to clean and now it stopped working.  That's what seems really strange about it, we switched to Java 1.7 a few months ago, and now it's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Luiggi Mendoza I solved it by using JDK 1.6 instead of 1.7. That did the trick, but I had to comment out a lot of code to compile it. Not that good a solution....

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar problem.
It occured that it was caused by switch that haven't got cases code.
While the error occured it looked somtheing like this:

```
switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
        case ACTION_OPEN_PID:
            break;
        case ACTION_OPEN_PPID:
            break;
        default:
    }
```

After adding simple console output to the cases the error was gone.

```
switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
        case ACTION_OPEN_PID:
            System.out.println(ACTION_OPEN_PID);
            break;
        case ACTION_OPEN_PPID:
            System.out.println(ACTION_OPEN_PPID);
            break;
        default:
    }
```