# Eclipse won't open with "an error has occurred"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Luna on a Mac (Yosemite).

Been using Eclipse for a few months now, when I open Eclipse this morning however I get a popup after the splash screen with "An error has occurred, see the log file."

**What I've tried:**

- Ran Eclipse with -clean argument
- I have no .snap file in the resources metadata folder to delete
- Completely removed my workspace (well, renamed it)

It doesn't get past the splash screen though.

Here's the log file in case it's helpful:

```
!SESSION 2015-06-18 07:55:02.645
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700 java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=macosx,
ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring
/Users/ralph/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation Command-line arguments: 
-os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring
/Users/ralph/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-18 07:55:06.268 !MESSAGE
Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid pc in LineNumberTable in class file org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Button
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570) 
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813) 
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2822)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1346)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:114)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: jdk is installed correctly  ? can you type java -version etc..

Comment: easiest way to fix: reinstall it.

Comment: are you able to open an empty workspace? If it works and you cannot fix the error in the previous workspace a workaround could be importing the code to the new workspace

Comment: Been using this setup for months, haven't touched the JDK or anything and was just working in my workspace last night. Also I can't even get an empty workspace, it doesn't get that far to even allow me to choose one. I think I might have to go with @Jegg 's suggestion.

Comment: I overlooked the obvious first step in debugging any computer troubles, just restart the computer. Error is gone. No complaints...

Answer (score 1):

Did you kill the jvm process with the task manager?? If you do, maybe your workspace has been corrupted. You have to make a new workspace. It happened to me several times.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111682/possible-causes-of-java-lang-classformaterror-invalid-pc-in-linenumbertable), they were able to fix a similar problem by switching JDK versions. Have you recently installed a new JDK?

Comment: Nope, afraid not. Thanks though.